# How to make Qty Attribute for Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, product

How can we make custom attributes as quantity.
I want to make quantity attributes so it would be easy for the customers buy in bulk with pre-defined options.

Example: X product with attributes 3,5,10 so when user select 3 and add to cart it gonna add X product 3 qty with showing total price for 3 or if they selected 5 then 5 qty it gonna add up with showing the price of 5 qty.

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHzMt.png)

Comment: You can simply use a [variable product](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/) with products variations (packs) of 3, 5, 10… So you will set in your variable product a product attribute "Pack" (or "quantity") choosing "Used for variations" option and you will be able to set each variation price.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: Select Product > Variable Product

Step 2: Create Attribute > Add Label as Quantity & Values 3, 5, 10 etc

Step 3: Create Variations > It will ask to create Variable Products using Attributes. Click Yes

Step 4: You can add Prices as per your Quantity in generated products after Step 3.

(You can also add images as per your quantities if you wish)

Comment: I want quantity to auto add rather than i need to customize manually!